# String doesn't parse to Int32 when concatenated with a string

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I am having homework, but something came up whilst doing it. I am parsing a string value to Int32 and later concatenate it to a string. The task is to get the age of the user and give him his age in 10 years.

However, when I try to add the var age to a string it doesn't stay as an int but as a string. here:  Console.WriteLine("Your age in 10 years will be: "+ age + 10); This outputs 2210 and not 32.

If I print only the var age + 10 it outputs 32.

Why do I get this result?

```
using System;

namespace _07App
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your age");
        var age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Your age in 10 years will be: "+ age + 10);
        Console.WriteLine(age + 10);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when you use `+` after a string, c# assumes that you're merging some strings. So it just act like this: `"Your age in 10 years will be:FirstName10"`

Comment: Work on fixing your naming conventions; `FirstName` is a terrible name for someone's age.

Comment: It might be wise to change the name of the variable `FirstName` to `age`

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvotes are for, it seems like an ok homework question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be an operator precedence problem, since your FirstName is added to the string before it is added to 10.

```
Console.WriteLine("Your age in 10 years will be: " +(FirstName + 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

use () when you are adding int values while concatenating with a string

```
Console.WriteLine("Your age in 10 years will be: "+ (FirstName + 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your age in 10 years will be: "+ (age+ 10));
```

Because `Console.WriteLine("Your age in 10 years will be: "+ age + 10);` will autoconvert age to String = "10" + "10" = "1010"